# Custom listView android fails

Tags: android, listview

so I have made a List view, called it "neighborhood".
it supposed to show a list of names of houses, number, and their passwords. for it, I have made a layout with 3 textviews.
the three lists that  CustomAdapter class gets are from SQL, which works(i debugged it  and it gets 3 full lists)

EDIT: now it just fails, and it gives me this error. I have changed the code to the suggested answers, and it fixed the last problems

the list:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/neighborhood"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/allAddresses"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/AddresSearch" />
```

this is the onCreate:

```
ListView neighborhood = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.neighborhood);
CustomAdapter customAdapter= new CustomAdapter(houseList,numList,passList);
neighborhood.setAdapter(customAdapter);
```

this  is the Adapter Helper class:

```
   class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    ArrayList<String> houseList ;
    ArrayList<String> numList ;
    ArrayList<String> passList ;

    public CustomAdapter(ArrayList<String>list1,ArrayList<String>list2,ArrayList<String>list3){
        this.houseList = list1;
        this.numList = list2;
        this.passList = list3;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return houseList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return houseList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_pass_item_view,null);

        TextView house = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.house);
        TextView num = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.num);
        TextView pass = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pass);

        house.setText(houseList.get(i).toString());
        num.setText(numList.get(i).toString());
        pass.setText(passList.get(i).toString());
        return null;
    }
}
```

and this is the custom layout for the listview: contains only 3 text view:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/num"
    android:layout_width="86dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="28dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/house"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/house"
    android:layout_width="86dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/pass"
    android:layout_width="86dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/num"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

EDIT:
this is the error it gives me now:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.omer.deliverypasses, PID: 17510
>       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.View.getImportantForAccessibility()' on a null object reference
>           at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2363)
>           at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1280)
>           at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1188)
>           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
>           at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:1227)
>           at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1572)
>           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:143)
>           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:401)
>           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
>           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
>           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
>           at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2643)
>           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2100)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1216)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1452)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
>           at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
>           at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
>           at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
>           at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Thank you very much

Comment: return list size in the public int getCount() . Dont return 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first change the listview height to **wrap_content** like this

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/neighborhood"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/allAddresses"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/AddresSearch" />
```

You have created another 3 different lists in the adapter constructor. The parent list always null. In this case, the app goes to crash. Without creating new list set values on parent list by using **this** before the list variable.

And then the adapter should be updated to this:

```
class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    ArrayList<String> houseList ;
    ArrayList<String> numList ;
    ArrayList<String> passList ;

    public CustomAdapter(ArrayList<String>list1,ArrayList<String>list2,ArrayList<String>list3){
        this.houseList = list1;
        this.numList = list2;
        this.passList = list3;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return houseList.size();
    }
   @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
      return position;
     }
    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_pass_item_view,null);

        TextView house = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.house);
        TextView num = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.num);
        TextView pass = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pass);

        house.setText(houseList.get(i).toString());
        num.setText(numList.get(i).toString());
        pass.setText(passList.get(i).toString());

        return view;
    }
}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Well you were right , it was another silly mistake of mine but now it fails and it gives me another error, I eddited the main question if you can have look? Thank you very much

Comment: Check my updated answer. getView method should return **view** not **null**.

Answer (score 1):

You done silly mistake that's why you are not able to get views.
Change there follow methods

```
 @Override
public int getCount() {
    return <HERE YOU HAVE TO GIVE SIZE>;
    // like return houseList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return <HERE YOU HAVE TO GIVE POSITION TO GET ITEM>;
    // like return houseList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return <HERE YOU HAVE TO PASS POSITION ONLY>;
     // like return position;
}
```

And your error solve.

Comment: It solved this problem, but i get an error, i debugged it and for some resone the getCount() returns null because houseList = null for some reason, d you know maby why it is null? althou i defined at as houselist=list1 and list1 is not null

Comment: You have created another 3 different lists in the adapter constructor. The parent list always null. In this case, the app goes to crash. Please try my answer. Hope your problem will be solved.